# What is wrong with these sine calculations in this html5 canvas implementation

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I know I can use guess-and-check the javascript math, but the results of that seem wildly incorrect, so I'd like to know exactly what is wrong with this math. (The sine doesn't display at all, but you can get it to if you change the numbers around -- it just doesn't make sense mathematically to me.) I checked with an online graphing calculator, the test is here (with the width and height of the canvas): https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ohs4l3jxkc and it seems correct. Here's a working jsFiddle of this implementation http://jsfiddle.net/JV5V3/ for ease of use.

html:

```
 <canvas style="width:100%;height:50px;"></canvas>
```

javascript:

```
makeWave($("canvas"));
function makeWave(canvas){
    var twoPI = Math.PI * 2;
    var width = canvas.css('width').replace(/\D/g,'');
    var height = canvas.css('height').replace(/\D/g,'');
    var xMulti = width/twoPI;

    var c = canvas[0];
    var context=c.getContext("2d");
    for(var i = 0; i < width*2; i++){
        var sineVal = (-1*Math.sin(i/xMulti)*(height/2)) + (height/2);
        sineVal = Math.round(sineVal);
        context.rect(i,sineVal,1,1);                
    }
    context.stroke();

    //scroll

    var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, width*2, height);
    var count = -1;
    setInterval(function(){
        context.clearRect(0, 0, width,height);
        context.putImageData(imageData, count+width, 0);
        context.putImageData(imageData, count, 0);
        --count;
        if(count <= -width) {
            clearInterval(this);
        }
    },60);
}
```

Here's an updated jsFiddle with a couple corrections: http://jsfiddle.net/JV5V3/2/ Still, it's not displaying what it's intended to.

Comment: What isn't working? What are your expected inputs and outputs?

Comment: It should show a scrolling sine wave, centered in the middle, with the top at the top and the bottom at the bottom of the canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
context.rect(i,-sineVal,1,1);
```

`sineVal` shouldn’t be made negative here; you’ve already added `height / 2` to it, so that’ll be above the visible portion of the canvas. [Updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/JV5V3/1/)

Comment: It just flips it upside down since (0,0) is the top left instead of the bottom left.

Comment: @JVE999: You should flip it before adding `height / 2`, then. (Or use `-sineVal + height`, but that’s just redundant.)

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Still, with `context.rect(i,sineVal,1,1);`, it doesn't display correctly (cuts most of it off at the top and its center is not in the middle at all). I updated the jsFiddle and added a link.

Comment: @JVE999: [Removing jQuery appears to fix it.](http://jsfiddle.net/JV5V3/3/) I suggest that everyone do that a little more often.

Comment: Well, that's interesting. Nice observation. What about line 23 not showing a copy of the image to make it repeat?

Comment: @JVE999: I don’t really know, but isn’t it cleaner just to redraw it every time? http://jsfiddle.net/JV5V3/4/

Comment: Not sure if it's cleaner. It works, though, which is nice. I was trying to minimize processor usage, however, and it is more processor intensive to keep calculating the sine and drawing the pieces one by one. Still, cool answer. I think using a sine table might bring it to about the same (not sure about processor usage in plotting lines vs. moving an image, just Math.sin() is pretty heavy).

Comment: This and some finagling jQuery with `document.getElementById($('parentClass').find('canvas').attr('id'))` eventually solved the problem completely. It would be nice to know why jQuery happens to do that and why the image doesn't plot twice as it should, but this turns out to work really well. With a Sine table I still can have the flexibility I was looking for with its current implementation. Thanks.